# Smooth isometric embedding of euclidean n-space into an arbitrarily small neighborhood of another euclidean space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It is not hard to isometrically embed the euclidean plane smoothly into an arbitrarily small neighborhood of euclidean 4-space: First embed a real line isometrically in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the plane, and then take the cartesian square. A paper of William S. Massey* proves that the image of any smooth isometric embedding of the plane in euclidean 3-space must be a generalized cylinder (i.e., the union of parallel lines), so is unbounded. Therefore 4 is the lowest possible dimension for this "crumpling" of the plane.

The same embedding idea provides a smooth isometric embedding of euclidean n-space into an arbitrarily small neighborhood of euclidean 2n-space.

Let C(n) denote the "crumpling function": C(n) is defined as the lowest dimension of a euclidean space into which euclidean n-space can be isometrically embedded smoothly, such that the image can lie in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of **R**<sup>C(n)</sup>. By the above, C(n) ≤ 2n.

What more might be known about C(n) ?

* "Surfaces of gaussian curvature zero in euclidean 3-space", Tohoku Math. J., 1962.

Comment: Note that your $C(n)$ is also the smallest number such that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a bounded, smooth isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{C(n)}$: As soon as you have such an isometric embedding into a ball of some radius $R>0$, you can construct one into a ball of radius $\epsilon$ for any  $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Interesting point, Robert! And having a bounded image seems to be a simpler, more natural condition than having an arbitrarily small image. (At the same time, the "arbitrarily small" definition seems to generalize to the other two simply connected manifolds S^n and H^n of constant sectional curvature, while at least for S^n the two conditions are clearly not equivalent.)

Comment: The statement for the surfaces (in much more general settings) appears in "Surfaces with bounded extrinsic curvature" by Pogorelov (it is 1956, but it is a book, so likely it was known earlier).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $C(n)=2{\cdot}n$.
The argument for $n=2$ works with minor changes; Cartan’s theorem is the only new ingredient.
(Thanks to Robert Bryant for suggesting it; see “Sur les variétés de courbure constante d’un espace euclidien ou noneuclidien” (1919) by Élie Cartan or “Isometric immersions of space forms in space forms” (1972) by John Moore.)

> **Cartan’s theorem.** Let $\alpha$ be the second fundamental form of a flat smooth $n$-manifold in $2{\cdot}n$-dimensional Euclidean space.
> Then either
> $$\alpha(X,Y)=\sum \ell_i(X)\cdot\ell_i(Y)\cdot e_i$$
> for an orthonormal basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ in the normal space $N$ and linearly independent linear functions $\ell_1,\dots,\ell_n$ on the tangent space $T$ or the *nullity index* of $\alpha$ is positive; that is, there is a nonzero vector $X\in T$ such that $\alpha(X,Y)=0$ for any $Y\in T$.

Suppose $M$ is a flat $n$-dimensional submanifold in $(2{\cdot} n-1)$-dimensional Euclidean space.
By Cartan’s theorem, each point $p\in M$ has a positive nullity index.

Choose a point $p\in M$ with minimal nullity index, say $k$.
By 1.18(iii) and 7.8 in "Submanifold theory" by  Marcos Dajczer and Ruy Tojeiro, $M$ contains a $k$-plane thru $p$. In particular, $M$ is not compact.

By the way, if a flat submanifold contains a straight line, then it splits. The proof is identical to the 2-dimensional case.