# Crumpling dimension: the least d for which a riemannian manifold embeds isometrically into an arbitrarily small ball of R^d

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In [Smooth isometric embedding of euclidean n-space into an arbitrarily small neighborhood of another euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442887/smooth-isometric-embedding-of-euclidean-n-space-into-an-arbitrarily-small-neighb) I recently asked the same question, but specifically for *euclidean spaces* of any dimension.

Here I note that this question can be asked for any C<sup>∞</sup> riemannian manifold, but the first questions one might ask are for the cases of the simply connected manifolds of constant sectional curvature K = -1, 0, 1.

Notation: Denote the unique simply connected d-dimensional manifold of constant sectional curvature K by **M**(K,d). (So e.g., **M**(-1,2) = **H**<sup>2</sup>, the hyperbolic plane; and **M**(1,3) = **S**<sup>3</sup>.)

Since K = 0 was already asked about in Question 442887 cited above, in *this question* I would like to know what may be known about ...

... the three simply connected manifolds **H**<sup>d</sup>, **R**<sup>d</sup>, **S**<sup>d</sup>, respectively, of constant curvature K = -1, 0, 1 in each dimension d.
(except that K = 0 was already addressed in Question 442887):

For any K ∊ **R**, let C(K,d) be defined as:

C(K,d)  =  the least **n** such that the **M**(K,d) can be C<sup>∞</sup> isometrically embedded into every nonempty open set of **R**<sup>**n**</sup>, or if there is no such n, C(K,d) = ∞ by definition.

**Question**: What is currently known about C(K,d) ?

We could equivalently define c(M) — for any C<sup>∞</sup> riemannian manifold M — as the least dimension d of a euclidean space **R**<sup>d</sup> into which M smoothly embeds isometrically into an arbitrarily small d-ball N(0) ⊂ **R**<sup>d</sup>.

Then of course c(**S**<sup>1</sup>) = 2. But I don't even know a proof that c(**S**<sup>2</sup>) is finite, no less what c(**S**<sup>2</sup>) is equal to. Only that by Liebmann's classical theorem, **S**<sup>2</sup> is a rigid surface in **R**<sup>3</sup>, and so we must have c(**S**<sup>2</sup>) ≥ 4.

(Edit:) I finally see the obvious: Since **S**<sup>d</sup> ⊂ **R**<sup>d+1</sup>, and for all n, **R**<sup>n</sup> can be crumpled into **R**<sup>2n</sup> (by [Smooth isometric embedding of euclidean n-space into an arbitrarily small neighborhood of another euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442887/smooth-isometric-embedding-of-euclidean-n-space-into-an-arbitrarily-small-neighb)), this shows that

d+2 ≤ c(**S**<sup>d</sup>) ≤ 2d+2,

so c(**S**<sup>2</sup>) ∊ {4,5,6}.

(Likewise, if any manifold M isometrically embeds in **R**<sup>n</sup>, then we must have c(M) ≤ 2n.)